# Need to accomodate gridView in my flutter

Tags: flutter, gridview, searchbar

[image]Im building an app that shows diets and also have a search bar to look for the diets.
I cant manage accomodate the search bar correctly like outside the gridviewer. heres the code of my view and how it actually looks. I dont want to be like another card

```
body: Container(
          child: GridView.builder(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              gridDelegate:
                  SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
              itemCount: dietsForDisplay.length + 1,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                if (diets.length == 0) {
                  return Container(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(60.0),
                      child: Text(
                        "No existen Dietas registradas por la nutrióloga.",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Color(0xFF002D53),
                            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                            fontSize: 25,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  return index == 0
                      ? _searchBar()
                      : _listItem(
                          context,
                          index - 1,
                        );
                }
              }),
        ));
  }
```

and the code for the searchBar and listItem are Cards

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your material app inside a Safe Area Widget

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to wrap your Scaffold widget with SafeArea so that your appbar won't get obstructed due to the notch. If you would want to add a search bar in your Scaffold's body, I would suggest using a `Column` to place your search bar on the top and your `GridView.builder()` on the bottom.  Here is how it looks like after my suggestions:

```
SafeArea(
 child:Scaffold(
  body: Column(
     children: <Widget>[
        //Search Bar here
        Expanded(
          child: //GridView.builder() here
        );
    ],
   ),
  ),
);
```

*If you want that page to be scrollable then replace Column with ListView